# How to attach a CSV file with the Google Chart API?

Tags: views, charts

I have created a Google Chart based View and it is working nicely.

How to give the facility as the user should be able to upload a CSV file and the data comes accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way using Google Chart API to "* to upload a csv file and the data comes accordingly*" (as in your question).

However, you may want to have a look at the [Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) module as a possible alternative (which already has an official release for both Drupal 7 and Drupal 8).

It is a graphical user interface, using the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) javascript library as its charting engine (which may require a commercial license though). It claims to support every Highcharts chart-type and option.

Some more details about this module:

- It defines a new content type (= *Chart*) used to add charts to your site.
- It creates a chart widget that can be used in your own content types.
- It integrates with the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module and provides an editor button to add charts to your WYSIWYG content (*CKeditor* and *TinyMCE* are supported).
- It provides an intuitive interface to configure charts through the Easychart plugin.
- It supports pasting of CSV data to create charts from it.
- [overheid.vlaanderen.be](http://overheid.vlaanderen.be/bedrijfsinformatie/toegankelijke-websites) contains some real world examples of a Drupal website with some charts created with Easycharts (ignore the text on that page if you're not familiar with this language, just concentrate on the charts).

Especially the bullet about "***It supports pasting of CSV data to create charts from it.***" seems close to what you're looking for.

## Resources:

- [Module documentation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/easychart/tree/README.txt?h=8.x-3.x).
- [Video demonstration](https://vimeo.com/137681122).